# Upgrading App to support iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4

I have developed an ios4 app and now want to upgrade it to ios5. What are the sort of things i need to be aware of in terms of the switch being successful and not causing any pains? My most important question is that if i do push a new change to apple, what will ios4 users see when an upgrade is available that supports only ios5 and up? Can they just ignore that update and continue using the ios4 version they had installed? Will the appstore error out if they try to download the ios5 upgrade anyway? What exactly will happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The biggest change in IOS 5.0 is the ARC project, so if you converted it to ARC it won't work with older devices like 3g (3gs can have ios 5.0 so it's safe).

Other than that, a user that has an iOS 5.0 device (or an upgraded one) would be able to get the update as soon as it is made available from apple store.

Keep in mind that lower end ios 5.0 devices might not have enough memory for the application though, it's the same that applies for ios 3 / ios 4 and sequentially ios 5/ios 6.0.

Comment: Of course there is always a factor of having unexpected results from deprecated methods and stuff. I am having one in my ios 5/ios 6 transition project and it really seems it is a bug...

Comment: So if a user is running ios4, can they still download my update for ios5 support and the app would still run? And it would break if i used an ios5 specific feature and the user is on ios4 right? Theres nothing in appstore that prevents an ios4 user from downloading an ios5 targeted app that uses arc for example? It would just crash on ios4 if it did correct?

Comment: No, if you compile it against ios 5 and he doesn't have ios 5 installed, it wont update the app, it will have the last ios 4 version made available to the public. You can also see this on the app metadata and on the app page of itunes. For new purchases, only ios 5 compatible users will buy it.

Comment: So why is it exactly that some of the app store updates im seeing recently list ios6 as a comment in their update alert. Im running ios5 right now on my iphone and yet i am able to get the updates for chrome etc which specifically state that they add ios6 compatibility. Im just not clear here

Comment: Possibly fixing bugs, like the one I'm having to run on ios 6.0, but it still runs on older ioses. Which is the minimum ios required on these apps? Can you give me an example app?

Comment: Well i just got an update request to update Chrome and it said added compatibility for ios6. So im not sure what the actual process is. I mean how do you specify the minimum os? All i want is my app not to break for existing users who are running it on ios4 when i release an update for my next build which will be targeted to ios5 with the arc management. how can i do this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17165/discussion-between-panagiotis-and-john-baum)